# Posting using App Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

I am trying to publish a feed using graph API using application access token. I am trying to achieve a result similar to the one in the URL below:

[Sample Image](http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/6963/graphapifeed.png)

I am able to create a feed but following two things I am still unable to figure out:

1) Linking the text in the feed to my application. Currently by clicking on the picture tag or name tag the user is redirected to the external link of the image (used in picture tag)

2) As you will notice in the image there is custom link button next to Comment. One says "Bonus Cash" and other says "Get Simoleons". How to do that?

I am currently using following graph api code. And in order to test it I am currently using Graph Api Explorer.

http://graph.facebook.com/myfbid/feed?&picture=http://www.link.com/linktoimage.jpg&name=Name Tag&caption=Caption Tag&description=Description Tag

If I add link tag to the above code than the type of feed changes from "via Application Name" to "shared a link via Application Name" and that is not what I want to achieve. I want it to say "via Application Name" like it is for other applications like i shared in the image above.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Linking the text in the feed to my application. Currently by clicking on the picture tag or name tag the user is redirected to the external link of the image (used in picture tag)

If you want a post to link somewhere – then actually post a `link` (parameter), and not only a picture.

Edit:
The “posts” in your screenshot might be Open Graph actions published for the user, though. That’s a completely different concept altogether; start reading about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

> 2) As you will notice in the image there is custom link button next to Comment. One says "Bonus Cash" and other says "Get Simoleons". How to do that?

Use the `actions` parameter.

Both are explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

1) Well as i said when i parse a link parameter it changes it to "shared link via application name" instead of "via application name"

2) I can't find any example for actions parameter. I found a blog post on facebook but the link given in it is broken. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/160/) The link you have given doesn't have any example. It just says use actions as array(action, link). I tried using that but doesn't work. Would appreciate if you could give a sample example or a link from where i can read more about it.

Comment: Ad 1), it’s hard to tell from your screenshot, but those might be Open Graph actions published for the user, and not links. I’ll update my answer on that. Ad 2), _“I tried but it didn’t work”_ is not a useful problem description. Please update your original question with what exactly you tried, and how the outcome was.

Comment: 1) will wait for an update. 
2) i tried parsing actions parameter as according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts - Actions: array of objects containing name and link

graph.facebook.com/myfbid/feed?&picture=http://www.link.com/linktoimage.jpg&name=Name Tag&caption=Caption Tag&description=Description Tag&actions=(my link,http://apps.facebook.com/myapp)

Comment: That’s not the right format for an “array” in this context – it has to be JSON-encoded.

Comment: `$actions = array(
'click me' => "http://apps.facebook.com/appname"
);

$apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/userid/feed";
$parameters = "?" . $appaccess . "&picture=http://linktopicture.com/picture.jpg&name=Name&method=post&action=".$actions;
$myurl = $apprequest_url . $parameters;
$result = file_get_contents($myurl);

I tried the above it still doesn't work.

Comment: $actions = array(
  'name' => "test",
  'link'          => "http://apps.facebook.com/myapp",
 ); Updated JSON Encoded array. I think i had the earlier one wrong   
`picture=http://www.obrotu.com/facebookclients/tradeguru2/images/anounment-icon.jpg&name=Name&method=post&action=".$actions` << not completely visible in earlier comment